# Insert or update in magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am inserting rows in a table like this in magento :

```
$table = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('table_name');

$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$write->insertMultiple($table,$rows);
```

`$rows` is the data that I am inserting its a 2D array, I have a primary key `'entity_id'` and another column `order_id` which have unique constraint.

Before inserting I want to check if order_id is present in table, if there is a row with `order_id` then update other wise insert.

I found `insertMultiple` which throws error if i insert a duplicate `order_id`. How can I do insert or update based on unique constraint column in table. Thanks

Edit :

I need some think like :

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

Comment: Which error does it throw?

Comment: I tried from console, if I insert a row with same value for a col which have unique constraint it throws  `ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'naveen1' for key 'uniq_key'`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::insertOnDuplicate()`:

```
/**
 * Inserts a table row with specified data.
 *
 * @param mixed $table The table to insert data into.
 * @param array $data Column-value pairs or array of column-value pairs.
 * @param array $fields update fields pairs or values
 * @return int The number of affected rows.
 * @throws Zend_Db_Exception
 */
public function insertOnDuplicate($table, array $data, array $fields = array())
```

You would have to insert each row separately, but you can define how duplicate keys should be handled. I think in your case you want to update the rows, so you just need `$table` and `$data` as params.